# Portlets not getting displayed when custom theme is applied

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have two portlets on a page. When the default theme is applied these portlets get displayed. But when I apply my own theme the portlets are not displayed. My theme has a header and footer which right now is getting displayed one after another with no space between the header and footer.

Why are my portlets not getting displayed when I apply my own created theme and what should be done?

***EDIT***

Here is the `portlet_normal.vm`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

#parse ($init)

<html>

<head>

    <script src="$javascript_folder/ga.js"></script>
    <script src="$javascript_folder/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="$javascript_folder/cufon-yui.js"></script>

    <script src="$javascript_folder/Omnes-Light_550.font.js"></script>
    <script src="$javascript_folder/Omnes-Medium_500.font.js"></script>
    <script src="$javascript_folder/Omnesbold_700.font.js"></script>
    <script src="$javascript_folder/OmnesReg_600.font.js"></script>

    <script src="$javascript_folder/common.js"></script>


    <title>$the_title - $company_name</title>

    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport" />

    $theme.include($top_head_include)
</head>

<body class="">

    <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper"> <div class="row-fluid"> <div class="span12" id="content-wrapper"> <div id="content">
        #if ($selectable) $theme.include($content_include) #else $portletDisplay.recycle() $portletDisplay.setTitle($the_title) $theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include) #end
    <div class="clear"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">

            <a href="#" class="icon">
            <img alt="t" title="t" src="$images_folder/ttsmalllogo.jpg">
            </a>

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="../Index.htm" title="t Capital">
                    <img alt="t" title="Tt" src="$images_folder/logo.jpg">
                </a> 
            </div>

            <div class="topnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../toplink/customerlogin.htm" title="Customer Login"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><img alt="Customer Login" src="$images_folder/loginicon.gif"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Customer " style="width: 62px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="73" height="13" style="width: 73px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Customer </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Login " style="width: 35px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="46" height="13" style="width: 46px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Login </cufontext></cufon></a></li>

                    <li><!-- Begin WebSols India Live Chat Button Code --><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><div id="comm100_FloatImageButton" style="float:left;padding-top:3px;"><div><div id="comm100_LiveChatDiv"></div><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><a href="http://www.comm100.com/livechat/" onclick="comm100_Chat();return false;" target="_blank" title="Live Chat Help"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><img src="$images_folder/chaticon.gif" style="border:0px" alt="Live Chat with operator" title="Live Chat"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Live " style="width: 27px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="38" height="13" style="width: 38px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Live </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Chat" style="width: 29px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="38" height="13" style="width: 38px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Chat</cufontext></cufon></a><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><script src="http://chatserver.comm100.com/js/LiveChat.js?siteId=100958&amp;planId=2103&amp;partnerId=-1" type="text/javascript"></script></div></div><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><!-- End WebSols India Live Chat Button Code --></li>

                    <li><img alt="" src="$images_folder/phoneicon.gif"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 3px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="14" height="13" style="width: 14px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="1800 " style="width: 33px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="44" height="13" style="width: 44px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>1800 </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="209 " style="width: 27px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="38" height="13" style="width: 38px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>209 </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="6060" style="width: 34px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="39" height="13" style="width: 39px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>6060</cufontext></cufon></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="searchbox">

                <input type="text" name="txtsearch" value="Search" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search'){this.select();this.value=''}">
                <a href="../toplink/search.htm">
                <img alt="Search" title="Search" border="0" src="$images_folder/search.jpg">
                </a> 
            </div>


            <div class="mainNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../Index.htm" title="Home"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Home" style="width: 38px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="44" height="13" style="width: 44px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Home</cufontext></cufon></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../aboutus/aboutus.htm" title="About Us"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="About " style="width: 47px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="58" height="13" style="width: 58px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>About </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Us" style="width: 17px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="23" height="13" style="width: 23px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Us</cufontext></cufon></span></a></li>
                    <li class="innerlinks "><a href="../products/homeloans.htm" title="Products"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Products" style="width: 69px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="75" height="13" style="width: 75px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Products</cufontext></cufon></span></a><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 2px; height: 10px;"><canvas width="11" height="10" style="width: 11px; height: 10px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon>
                    <div class="inner_nav" style="display: none;">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li><a href="../products/homeloans.htm" title="Home data"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Home " style="width: 34px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="44" height="11" style="width: 44px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Home </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loans" style="width: 36px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="41" height="11" style="width: 41px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loans</cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                            <li><a href="../products/loansp.htm" title="Loans p"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loan " style="width: 31px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="41" height="11" style="width: 41px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loan </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Against " style="width: 49px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="58" height="11" style="width: 58px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Against </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Property" style="width: 56px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="61" height="11" style="width: 61px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Property</cufontext></cufon></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="innerlinks "><a href="../loancentre/loancentre.htm" title="Loan c"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loan " style="width: 37px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="48" height="13" style="width: 48px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loan </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Centre" style="width: 51px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="56" height="13" style="width: 56px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Centre</cufontext></cufon></span></a><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 2px; height: 10px;"><canvas width="11" height="10" style="width: 11px; height: 10px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon>
                    <div class="inner_nav" style="display: none;">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <!--<li><a href="#" title="Fair Practices Code of t">Fair Practices Code of t </a></li>-->
                            <li><a href="../products/chl.htm" title="Customize"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Customize " style="width: 64px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="74" height="11" style="width: 74px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Customize </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="My " style="width: 18px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="27" height="11" style="width: 27px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>My </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loan" style="width: 29px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="33" height="11" style="width: 33px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loan</cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                            <li><a href="../loancentre/plr.htm" title="Interest Rates"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Interest " style="width: 53px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="63" height="11" style="width: 63px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Interest </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Rates " style="width: 36px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="45" height="11" style="width: 45px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Rates </cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                            <li><a href="../loancentre/faqs.htm" title="FAQs for Home "><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="FAQs " style="width: 30px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="39" height="11" style="width: 39px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>FAQs </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="for " style="width: 24px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="33" height="11" style="width: 33px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>for </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Home " style="width: 34px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="44" height="11" style="width: 44px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Home </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loans " style="width: 38px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="47" height="11" style="width: 47px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loans </cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                            <li><a href="../loancentre/faqs_lap.htm" title="FAQs for Loan"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="FAQs " style="width: 30px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="39" height="11" style="width: 39px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>FAQs </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="for " style="width: 24px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="33" height="11" style="width: 33px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>for </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loan " style="width: 31px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="41" height="11" style="width: 41px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loan </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Against " style="width: 49px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="58" height="11" style="width: 58px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Against </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Property " style="width: 58px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="67" height="11" style="width: 67px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Property </cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                            <li><a href="../quickylink/calculators.htm" title="Calculator"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Calculator " style="width: 72px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="82" height="11" style="width: 82px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Calculator </cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../homeloanguide/homeloanguide.htm" title="Home"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Home " style="width: 40px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="51" height="13" style="width: 51px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Home </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Loan " style="width: 37px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="48" height="13" style="width: 48px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Loan </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Guide" style="width: 40px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="45" height="13" style="width: 45px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Guide</cufontext></cufon></span></a></li>
                    <li class="innerlinks"><a href="../mediacenter/mediacentre.htm" title="Media Centre"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Media " style="width: 42px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="53" height="13" style="width: 53px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Media </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Centre" style="width: 51px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="56" height="13" style="width: 56px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Centre</cufontext></cufon></span></a><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 2px; height: 10px;"><canvas width="11" height="10" style="width: 11px; height: 10px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon>
                    <div class="inner_nav" style="display: none;">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li><a href="../mediacenter/mediacentre.htm" title="TV Commercials"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Advertisements" style="width: 95px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="100" height="11" style="width: 100px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Advertisements</cufontext></cufon></a></li>
                            <!-- <li class="last"><a href="../mediacenter/testimonials.htm" title="Testimonials">Testimonials</a></li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </li>      
                    <li class="innerlinks "><a href="../contactus/contactus.htm" title="Contact Us"><span><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Contact " style="width: 63px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="74" height="13" style="width: 74px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Contact </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Us" style="width: 17px; height: 13px;"><canvas width="23" height="13" style="width: 23px; height: 13px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Us</cufontext></cufon></span></a><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 2px; height: 10px;"><canvas width="11" height="10" style="width: 11px; height: 10px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon>
                    <div class="inner_nav" style="display: none;">
                        <ul class="list">

                            <li class="last"><a href="../contactus/customer_grievance.htm" title="Customer Grievance Redressal"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Customer " style="width: 61px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="70" height="11" style="width: 70px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Customer </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Grievance " style="width: 63px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="72" height="11" style="width: 72px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Grievance </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Redressal" style="width: 61px; height: 11px;"><canvas width="67" height="11" style="width: 67px; height: 11px; top: 1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Redressal</cufontext></cufon></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="external" href="http://www.t.com">

                    <img src="$images_folder/btnapplynow.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12" id="content-wrapper"> 
                    <div id="content"> 

                        #if ($selectable) $theme.include($content_include) 
                        #else $portletDisplay.recycle() $portletDisplay.setTitle($the_title) $theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include)
                        #end 
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>



        <div id="footer">
            <div class="inner_footer">
                <div class="links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="first"><a href="http://www.t.com/" title="Tt" target="_blank">tg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.t.com/" title="T" target="_blank">T</a></li>
                        <!--    <li><a href="http://www.t.com/" title="Ta" target="_blank">Ta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.t.html" title="Tt" target="_blank">Tt</a></li> -->
                        <li><a href="http://www.tt.com/" title="Tt " target="_blank">Tt</a></li>
                        <li class="last">
                            <!-- <a href="/export/system/modules/org.t.templates/resources/Forms-Brochure/Fair_Practices_Code_Final.pdf" title="Fair Practices Code" target="_blank">Fair Practices Code</a> -->
                            <a href="http://www.tt.com/" title="Tt " target="_blank">Tt</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="socialbox" style="width:178px;">
                    <p class="text">Follow Us:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/t" title="Facebook" target="_blank" class="fb"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/#%21/t" title="Twitter" target="_blank" class="tw"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://youtu.be/ziZzcWrpQdQ" target="_blank" class="yt" title="Youtube"></a></li>
                        <li><a rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/103254708211301626088" target="_self" style="border-style:none;float:left;">

                        <img src="$images_folder/G_plus.jpg" alt="Google +" style="border-style:none;float:left;" border="0"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="links dis">
                    <ul>

                        <li class="first">

                            <a href="http://www.tt.com/export/system/modules/org.t.templates/resources/Forms-Brochure/Fair_Practices_Code_Final.pdf" title="Fair Practices Code" target="_blank">Fair Practices Code</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                        </li><li>

                            <a href="http://www.t.com/export/system/modules/org.t.templates/resources/Forms-Brochure/Draft_legal_disclaimer.pdf" title="Legal Disclaimer" target="_blank">Legal Disclaimer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <a href="http://www.t.com/export/system/modules/org.t.templates/resources/Forms-Brochure/t_H12011_12.pdf" title="Investor Information" target="_blank">Investor Information</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <a href="http://www.t.com/export/system/modules/org.t.templates/resources/Forms-Brochure/t_Privacy_Commitment.pdf" title="Privacy Commitment" target="_blank">Privacy Commitment</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.t.com/contactus/contactus.htm" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="http://www.t.com/footer/sitemap.htm" title="Sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p class="copyright">© 2011 t t</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>

</html>
```

NOTE:

div that needs to be added between header and footer. its css not getting displayed

```
        <div class="products" style="width:1000px;">


  <div class="tvc box">
  <img alt="ADVISORY" title="ADVISORY" src="Index_files/ADVISORY.PNG">
  <div class="txt">
  <p class="hdtxt"><cufon style="width: 78px; height: 16px;" alt="ADVISORY" class="cufon cufon-canvas"><canvas style="width: 85px; height: 16px; top: 1px; left: -1px;" height="16" width="85"></canvas><cufontext>ADVISORY</cufontext></cufon></p>
  <p>Read more about our Advisory against Fraudulent Websites.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://t.com/Forms-Brochure/Advisory_for_ALL_SITES.pdf" title="Know More">Know More</a> </div>

  <div class="tvc box">
  <img alt="Branch Locator" title="Branch Locator" src="Index_files/branchlocator.jpg">
  <div class="txt">
  <p class="hdtxt"><cufon style="width: 68px; height: 16px;" alt="BRANCH " class="cufon cufon-canvas"><canvas style="width: 82px; height: 16px; top: 1px; left: -1px;" height="16" width="82"></canvas><cufontext>BRANCH </cufontext></cufon><br><cufon style="width: 73px; height: 16px;" alt="LOCATOR" class="cufon cufon-canvas"><canvas style="width: 80px; height: 16px; top: 1px; left: -1px;" height="16" width="80"></canvas><cufontext>LOCATOR</cufontext></cufon></p>
  <p>Use our branch locator to find the branch closest to you!</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.t.com/quickylink/branchlocater.htm" title="Know More">Know More</a> </div>


  <div class="tvc box">

  <img alt="EMI Calculator" title="EMI Calculator" src="Index_files/emicalculator.jpg">
  <div class="txt">
  <p class="hdtxt"><cufon style="width: 30px; height: 16px;" alt="EMI " class="cufon cufon-canvas"><canvas style="width: 44px; height: 16px; top: 1px; left: -1px;" height="16" width="44"></canvas><cufontext>EMI </cufontext></cufon><br><cufon style="width: 102px; height: 16px;" alt="CALCULATOR" class="cufon cufon-canvas"><canvas style="width: 109px; height: 16px; top: 1px; left: -1px;" height="16" width="109"></canvas><cufontext>CALCULATOR</cufontext></cufon></p>
  <p>Knowing your home loan EMI is just a click away!</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.t.com/quickylink/emicalculator.htm" title="Know More" class="sec">Know More</a> </div>
  <div class="tvc box">

  <img alt="FAQs" title="FAQs" src="Index_files/faqs.jpg">
  <div class="txt">
  <p class="hdtxt"><cufon style="width: 39px; height: 16px;" alt="FAQs" class="cufon cufon-canvas"><canvas style="width: 48px; height: 16px; top: 1px; left: -1px;" height="16" width="48"></canvas><cufontext>FAQs</cufontext></cufon></p>
  <p>Get the answers to frequently asked questions here.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.t.com/loancentre/faqs.htm" title="Know More" class="sec">Know More</a> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you made any changes in portal_normal.vm file?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya
Yes. I have made changes to this file to create my own theme.

Comment: I have changed the entire portal_normal.vm according to theme that I want.

Comment: If you can provide that changes here. that would be helpful to trace issue. can you check if it has one div with class wrapper

Comment: @PankajKathiriya : Yes I have div with id "wrapper". Inside that div i have a div with id "header" and another div with id "footer"

Comment: Can you provide content of portal_normal.vm here?

Comment: You would get the help you require only if you can paste your `portal_normal.vm` file. But if you don't want the super secret theme development to leak out, then check if you have the following code in your `portal_normal.vm` file:
`<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper"> <div class="row-fluid"> <div class="span12" id="content-wrapper"> <div id="content"> #if ($selectable) $theme.include($content_include) #else $portletDisplay.recycle() $portletDisplay.setTitle($the_title)  $theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include) #end <div class="clear"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div>`

Comment: Also check if any CSS is hiding the content of the `<div>` I have pasted above. thanks

Comment: @PrakashK : Thank you Prakash for the lead you gave me.. upvoted your answer.

Comment: It was not an answer, it was a comment. But if you want to upvote I have made that as an answer so that you can actually upvote and benefit me :-) Thanks

Comment: @PrakashK :  I have included the portal_normal.vm file here.
THe portlets are getting displayed on top before the header and footer follows immediatly after header.

Comment: Why are you included the code containing `$theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include)` twice? One is at the start and one is in between the header and footer `<div>`. remove one at the top.

Comment: @PrakashK : 
Done that.. I have another div that needs to be added between header and footer but when i add it,its css is not getting applied for it. each div with class "tvc box" needs to come one after another in one horizontal line

Comment: If you can see everything properly with the portlet and contents but the layout is not proper than that is a CSS issue rather than a liferay issue. How did you include the CSS file in the Theme?

Comment: in inner.css inside css folder. This inner.css is imported by custom.css

Comment: are you sure if the css file is loaded at all? And then if the CSS is proper.

Comment: It is from the same css file that css is getting applied to header and footer. they are getting displayed properly.

Comment: check with firebug addon firefox or developer tools in chrome if the CSS is being loaded. Try clearing the browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your `portal_normal.vm`, to give you the exact solution.

But if you don't want the super secret theme development to leak out, then check if you have the following code in your `portal_normal.vm` file:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12" id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                #if
                    ($selectable) $theme.include($content_include)
                #else 
                    $portletDisplay.recycle()

                    $portletDisplay.setTitle($the_title)

                    $theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include)
                #end 

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also it would be nice to check if any custom `CSS` is hiding the content of any of the `<div>`s above.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. For your benefit :) But yea it gave me lead. Thanks!